# Image Lazy Loader place holder size

Tags: jquery, image, jquery-lazyload

I am using lazy loading to show my images in the web. The source is follows

http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

The page include images thumbnails and the size is around 300 x 100. So i specified width and height as specified. So for thumbnails its working fine.

I need to show one loading gif as placeholder so that before loading this loading gif will be shown in the thumbnail place. For this i changed the placeholder option in the js file.

But there is no option to specify size for the place holder so the gif stretched to the size of original image. I also didn't get any option to dynamically change css class with specific sizes.

Comment: You can use static overlay div with loading image until original image is not loaded, when lazy loader finish update the html of overlay.

Comment: @RanjeetSingh the issue is in size. when i not specified the gif stretch to the holder. so loading gif have 16x16 but the holder have 300 x 100 for the original image

Comment: can you try giving inline style to loading gif ? or try giving a class with height, width via css !important ?

Comment: sorry i din't get. can you please give an example. You mean like i give inner div in the img tag with specific css fot that div?

Comment: as of now loading gif goes stretch out. I want to say that can you try to give inline style to loading gif ? or via css class .static_class{height:16px !important;width:16px!important;}

Comment: ok so after original image loaded how the size is changed. again the original image also in 16 x 16. That is don't want. Otherwise i remove this specific class when image loaded. But I didn't get a place to remove this class in this lazy load plugin methods

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106671/discussion-between-akhil-and-ranjeet-singh).